# Elasticsearch only master node work

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute some queries on `Index A` from python (aggs queries) codes to ES server.

**My config:**

`Index A` sharded for `node-superman-1` -> `node-superman-4`

`node-superman-1` -> `node-superman-4` were **data** and **master** node.

```
node.master: true 
node.data: true 
node.ingest: true
```

`node-superman-client-41` just was a node, I tried to call to this node.

```
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
```

But only `node-superman-3` worked (I tried to run multi threads and later threads must to be waited).

**Python code:**

I used `elasticsearch` to connect to `node-superman-client-41`

Using search function `elasticsearch.search`:

```
data = elasticsearch.search(index='Index_A', body=query, 
request_timeout=120)
```

`query` just like normal query `{ query: { ... }, aggs: { ... } }`

I created multi connections and used in multi threads:

[image]

So why? How can I share for another node (1, 2, 4)?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: why is that an issue? ES decides which node will handle your requests and usually picks the most appropriate one. The fact that your master node is handling the requests is a pure coincidence in my opinion. Why don't you send your queries to `node-superman-client-41` only since this is his purpose in life?

Comment: Hi @Val, only node-superman-3 ran everytime, and another requests must to be waited until the current request is processed.

Comment: how did you set up your Python client?

Comment: @Val I used `elasticsearch` to connect to `node-superman-client-41` then used search function `elasticsearch.search` : `data = elasticsearch.search(index='user_information', body=query,request_timeout=120)`

Comment: please update your question with the client setup code, as it's more legible

Comment: Hi @Val, I updated my post!

Comment: I'm interested in `get_elastic_connection()`

Comment: Hi @Val
The reason is my nodes had not the same hardware.

`node-superman-3`  (the selected master node) had weak hardware than other nodes. So, It handled requests slower with other nodes. 

I turned off `node-superman-3` and got fine result. Every node (1, 2, 4) run in same usage.

Comment: gotcha, glad you figured out